# the subgroups of special linear group

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G={\rm PSL}(2,8)$. So $|G|=2^3 \times 3^2 \times 7$. Let $ P \in {\rm Syl}_2(G)$, $Q \in {\rm Syl}_3(G)$ and $R \in {\rm Syl}_7(G)$. I know $P \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ and $Q,R$ are cyclic of order $9,7$, respectively. Now i want to find the structure of $N_G(H)$, where $ H \cong C_2 \times C_2$.

${\bf My Try}$: Since $P$ is abelian, $P \le C_G(H) \le N_G(H)<G$. Thus $8 \mid |N_G(H)| \mid 504$.

Comment: It is not true that $P \cong D_8$. In fact $P \cong C_2^3 \cong ({\mathbb F}_8,+)$. Also, since $|P|=8$, we clearly have $8\,\mid\,|N_G(P)|$. In fact $|N_G(P)| = 56$.

Comment: that is $P$ is elementary abelian? why?

Comment: As I  said, it's because it's isomorphic to the additive group of the field.

Comment: I edited it, thanks

Comment: Note that ${\rm PSL}(2,8) \cong {\rm SL}(2,8)$, and in ${\rm SL}(2,8)$ you can take $N_G(P)$ to be the griup of upper triangular matrices with determinant $1$, which has orde r$56$.